# Why do I get a getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() "insecure origins" error in Chrome on localhost?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, geolocation, google-geolocation

I'm working on a website in my local development environment (Ubuntu 16.04) and testing the website on Chrome (58) via http://localhost.example/ - which connects to the local web server.

Running this Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
});
```

Triggers this error:

> [Deprecation] getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() no longer work
>   on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider
>   switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See
>   https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins for more details.

Why is that? I understand that public facing websites need to be running HTTPS for the geolocation library/ functionality to work. We have a number of public websites running similar code across HTTPS.

However according to the [depreciation documentation](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins):

> localhost is treated as a secure origin over HTTP, so if you're able
>   to run your server from localhost, you should be able to test the
>   feature on that server.

The above Javascript is running in-line in the HTML body loaded via http://localhost.example/test-page/ - so why am I getting the "insecure origins" error in Chrome?

Firefox (53) shows the in browser access location prompt, as expected.

Comment: Can you run it off of your local machine using https?

Comment: perhaps  because `localhost` !== `localhost.example`

Comment: also, Firefox as of version 55 will also have the https limitation - in firefox `Locally delivered files such as http://localhost and file:// paths are considered to have been delivered securely.` - so, it will work the same in the fox as the chrum

Comment: @JaromandaX - I can confirm that http://localhost/test-page/ works. If you'd like to add that as an answer I'll select as correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome considers localhost over http as secure. As you are using hostnme localhost.example over http, this is not considered as secure.

Note: Firefox will behave similarly as of Firefox 55

Comment: is there any way to test?

Comment: test what? this has been a *thing* in browsers for a **long** time

Answer (score 0):

SSL over HTTP protocol ensures the private communication within Client and Server. The information might transmit through the private networks while transmission. Any third person (hacker) on the network can steal that information. To avoid that browser forces the user to use a secure connection.

On the local server, the information is not going beyond our private local network since there is not need of this kind of security. So we can expect a browser to allow geolocation without SSL on the local server. Ideally, the browser developer should skip this validation for localhost and 127.0.0.1 or similar origins.

There must be tricks available to avoid such issues i.e. you can install self-signed SSL certificate on the local server or you can edit the Chrome configuration file to allow domains to access the geolocation, webcam etc.

Helpful links,

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins

https://ngrok.com/